# How to determine the data type of the outcome of the spread operator in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators, spread-syntax

What is the data type of the elements outputted by spread? And is it possible to call only one element after spread, like with arrays?

Here is the example:

```
let ages = [1,2,3,1,4];
let chars = ['a','b','c'];


console.log(ages); // shows array> (5) [1, 2, 3, 1, 4]
console.log(...ages); // shows this> 1 2 3 1 4 - ??

console.log(typeof(ages[1]));// number

console.log(typeof(chars));// object

console.log(typeof(chars[1])); //string

//console.log(typeof(...ages)); - NOT WORKING
//console.log(typeof(...ages[1])); - NOT WORKING
```

Thanks!

Comment: unclear what you are asking... you are asking how to get all the types? Does not make sense to use spread in this manner...

Comment: FYI typeof is not a method so you do not need the (). eg `console.log(typeof ages[1]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the data type of the elements outputted by spread?

Each member of the array will have its own type.

> And is it possible to call only one element after spread, like with arrays?

The point of a spread is to take *all* members of an array and spread them out.

If you want to access one member, then you shouldn't be using spread in the first place.

> ```
> console.log(typeof(...ages))
> ```

This doesn't make sense. `typeof` tells you the type of *something* not *many things*.

Use a loop instead of a spread operator if you want to do something to each member of an array.

```
ages.forEach(member => { console.log(typeof member); });
```

> ```
> console.log(typeof(...ages[1]));
> ```

Also doesn't make sense. `ages[1]` is the number 2. It isn't an iterable object. You can't spread it. If you want the type of that element then just:

```
console.log(typeof ages[1]);
```

Comment: `...ages` is not even "many things". It's syntax that is only valid in array literals or function calls, not for `typeof` operands.

Comment: Thank you, Quentin! All clear now :) Thanks Bergi for the additional clarification.